# Remove duplicate Source to Destination (eg. for 2 different entries(rows), Delhi to Mumbai and Mumbai to Delhi, output should be one)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in sql server database.

```
Source     Destination     Fare
-------------------------------
Delhi      Mumbai           100
Mumbai     Delhi            100
London     New York         500
```

I have to write an sql query that produce following result.

```
Source     Destination     Fare
-------------------------------
Delhi      Mumbai           100
London     New York         500
```

if you swap Source and Destination and it matches from any previous row then remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select source, destination, fare
from t
where source < destination
union all
select source, destination, fare
from t
where source > destination and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.source = t.destination and t2.destination = t.source
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option deals with duplicates by sorting sources and destinations:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Source < Destination THEN Source ELSE Destination END AS Source,
        CASE WHEN Source < Destination THEN Destination ELSE Source END AS Destination,
        Fare
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT DISTINCT Source, Destination, Fare
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen, your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

you can use union and comparison

```
with cte as    
(
select 'Delhi' as source, 'Mumbai' as destination, 100 as fare
union all
select 'Mumbai' as source, 'Delhi' as destination, 100 as fare
union all
select 'London','New York',500
)   select  source,destination,fare from cte
    where source<destination
    union
    select  source,destination,fare        
    from cte where source<destination
```

output

```
source  destination     fare
Delhi   Mumbai          100
London  New York        500
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try query:

```
select min(Source), max(Destination), Fare 
from 
    tbl 
where Source in (select Destination from tbl) 
group by Fare
union all
select * from 
    tbl 
where Source not in (select Destination from tbl)
```

Comment: What happens if two different routes happen to share the same fare?  Your approach would group those two routes into one single route.  Not my downvote (see the comment below for that).

Comment: This will give wrong result of London->New York fare is also 100